# Is it good practice use Progress Dialog As Singleton Class

Tags: android, singleton, progressdialog

I have Progress Dialog Class which is singleton

```
public class ProgressDialogManager {

private static ProgressDialogManager manager = null;

private Context context;

private ProgressDialog pDialog = null;

private ProgressDialogManager(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

}

public static ProgressDialogManager getInstance(Context context) {
    if (manager == null)
        manager = new ProgressDialogManager(context);
    return manager;
}

public void showDialog(String msg) {
    if (pDialog == null)
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.context);
    pDialog.setMessage(msg);
    pDialog.show();
}

public void closeDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
 }
}
```

when getInstance(this) method multiple activity  I get  and error

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window — token android.os.BinderProxy@447a6748 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

**my question is**
Is it Good practice  Progress Dialog As  Singleton Class  and what is the reason of Error how to solved it

Comment: It is only good practice when all the other practices are worse. Then it isn't good practice, only the least worst. The reasons are manifold, and best learnt by experience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window

This exception occurs when you are trying to show `dialog` over an `Activity` which has been finished and you are passing its `context` to show the `dialog` in another `Activity`.

**Your code creates that Scenario:**

Suppose you created an instance of `ProgressDialogManager` in an `Activity` and shown the `dialog` in that `Activity` which would work fine.

Now you **destroyed** that `Activity` and moved to another `Activity` but your previously created `ProgressDialogManager` instance is not destroyed because you made it singleton. Now if you try to get the instance of `ProgressDialogManager` it will return previously created `ProgressDialogManager` and it contains the `context` of Previous `Activity` which has been destroyed.

Now if you will try to show the dialog then it will throw this exception because you are trying to show the dialog using dead `context`.

To solve this problem pass the `context` also in `showDialog`and remove the `null` check on `dialog` in `showDialog`.

```
public void showDialog(String msg, Context context) {
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pDialog.setMessage(msg);
    pDialog.show();
}
```

> Note : Don't make Context as a singleton member of any class because
>   context keeps changing all the time

Comment: Excellent Explanation , thanks , Now what should I do to solved it ??

Comment: @NirzonPop make other member as singleton but not context. I have updated the answer please look at it.

Comment: you safe my day . problem solved